# Java Program assistance

Tags: java

I have been given an assignment to do the following

1. Generate id numbers for employees - Each id number must meet the following requirements:
   a. It must be a prime number
   b. It must not match a previously generated ID number
   c. It must be exactly 5 digits in length
2. Store Employee data – for this feature the application must allow you to enter a new employee’s full name and their assigned ID number. These must be stored in the application.

So far am unsure of if am doing the correct thing but I have some code I started up below...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    primenum();
}

public static void primenum() {

    int max = 20000;
    System.out.println("Generate Prime num" + max);
    for (int i = 10000; i < max; i++) {
        boolean isPrimeNumber = true;
        for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                isPrimeNumber = false;
            }
        }
        // print the number if prime
        if (isPrimeNumber) {
            System.out.println(i + " ");
        }
    }
}

public static void ID() {

    String[] emp = new String[10];
    emp[0] = "John";
    emp[1] = "Mary";
    emp[2] = "James";
    emp[3] = "chris";
    emp[4] = "charles";
}
```

I have just created an array that will hold some names.. but my main objective I want to get is for the next prime number generated to be stored in each of the `emp[]` associated with a name .. so for eg. `emp[0]` which is john I want him to be able to receive the next prime number for the `primenum()` method.. I am unsure of how to do this and will love all help apprecited.

Comment: Computing prime numbers every time the program runs is somewhat inefficient. I'd compute them in advance and save them in a file. Then just read them in again. It's only 8363 that meet the requirements.

Comment: Sidenote: for better prime-finding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: _"Store Employee data – for this feature the application must allow you to enter a new employee’s full name and their assigned ID number. These must be stored in the application."_ - Does that mean persistent? Like in a DB or fata file?

Answer (score 1):

To associate a prime number with your employee name:

Create a custom object which is responsible for relation between employee object and prime number(ID) like below :

```
public class EmployeeNameAndId {

    private Employee employee;

    private Integer id;

    // constructors, getters, setters here

}
```

Now you need to use this object in your main class like below :

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<EmployeeNameAndId> l = new ArrayList<>();
        l.add(new EmployeeNameAndId("John", generatePrimeId());
        l.add(new EmployeeNameAndId("Mary", generatePrimeId());
        l.add(new EmployeeNameAndId("James", generatePrimeId());
        l.add(new EmployeeNameAndId("Chris", generatePrimeId());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks bro.. basically is something like that but to get a clearer understandiing the program had 3 parts idk if i will make any different in helping.. here is the 3rd part.

Comment: Search employee data – for this feature the application must allow two options. The user must be prompted to enter either:
a. A user’s first and last names – In this case your application must use this data to search through the records and retrieve the corresponding id number for the given name. You are free to assume that there will never be two employees with the same first and last names.
b. A user’s ID number - In this case your application must retrieve and display the corresponding username (full name). Again, there will never be an instance where two employees have the same ID number

Comment: Hi @Kevin, for searching part you can use any logic which can help you solve your query. Like you can iterate through your data and compare each one with input until you find requested one (Java 8 streams might help you to accomplish it in single line).

Comment: @Kevin if you need help with its performance or anything like that, let me know and I will try to help you out. Good luck!

Comment: honest i need help with the entire code lol.. i do understand code like viewing it but writing it is my issue... i am new to like basic knowledge as in variables,methods ,arrays, using scanner ...nothing more really so this what i got to do is lil confusing for me.. but the program i believe its like i want to generate employee id's that is 5 digits and must be a prime number.. after its like i need to store an employee full name and their assigned ID number which i believe i will get from the generated number.. after i must enter an id for an employee and display the associated name..

Answer (score 1):

use this solution:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class PrimeNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String,Integer> map=new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        map.put("John", nextPrime(1));
        map.put("Mary", nextPrime(map.get("John")));
        map.put("James", nextPrime(map.get("Mary")));
        map.put("chris", nextPrime(map.get("James")));
        map.put("charles", nextPrime(map.get("chris")));
        
        for(Entry<String, Integer> e:map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(e.getKey()+": "+e.getValue());
        }
    }
    
    public static int nextPrime(int input){
          int counter;
          input++;
          while(true){
            int l = (int)  Math.sqrt(input);
            counter = 0;
            for(int i = 2; i <= l; i ++){
              if(input % i == 0)  counter++;
            }
            if(counter == 0)
              return input;
            else{
              input++;
              continue;
            }
          }
        }
}
```